# TypeScript: Unit testing the genrated Js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, karma-runner

i want to test my file number.d.ts like verifying if this file contains in its class such functions by testing the generated file .js.

Here is file number.d.ts  :

```js
// file number.d.ts
export interface Options{
    maxDec?: number;
    minDec?: number;
}    

export class Number {
    static add (value1: number, value2: number): number;
}

// to import the class 
const NumberConv = require('../src/number-conv');

// to import the interface ??
```

Here is the unit tests for the file number.d.ts

```js
// tests for the number.d.ts
import { NumberConv, Options } from '../src/number-conversion';

describe('number.d.ts', () => {
  it('add', () => {
    const value: number = 2;
    const value1: number = 4;
    NumberConv.add(value, value1);
  });
}

// the generated file .js for the .ts file

"use strict";
const number_conversion_1 = require('../src/number-conversion');
describe('number.d.ts', () => {
    it('add', () => {
       const value = 2;
       const value1 = 4;
        number_conversion_1.NumberConversion.add(value, value1);
    });
}
```

and here is the tsconfig.json file to add compile Options:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "tests/",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noResolve": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Is there any tips to prevent addind NumberConversion in the generated file like that: `number_conversion_1.NumberConversion.add(value, value1);`. I need the js file to call the add method like that:
number_conversion_1.add(value, value1);
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code includes a `require` call. How are you running your JavaScript tests in karma? With Browserify or Webpack or something else?

Comment: to test this file , I called the file d.ts like that: `const myClass = require('../src/number')`. And then to test for example a method, i did something like that: `describe('number.d.ts', () => {
  it('add', () => {
    const value1: number = 2;
    const value2: number= 4;
    NumberConversion.add(value, locale);
  });` . And i'm running my Javascript tests in karma using webpack.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Perhaps it would be clearer if you were to post your `karma.conf.js` file?

Comment: @cartant i agree , my question was quite unclear, Hope that it's more clear now.